# How to remove property of nested object from MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB document like this :

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5589044a7019e802d3e9dbc5"),
    "sessionId": LUUID("f49d4280-ced0-9246-a3c9-a63e68e1ed45"),
    "teamId": LUUID("6ef7d1a8-f842-a54c-bd8c-daf6481f9cfc"),
    "variableId": LUUID("59d1b512-eee2-6c4b-a5b5-dda546872f55"),
    "values": {
        "725400": 691.0000000000000000,
        "725760": 686.0000000000000000,
        "726120": 683.0000000000000000,
        "726480": 681.0000000000000000,
        "726840": 679.0000000000000000,
        "727200": 678.0000000000000000,
        "727560": 677.0000000000000000,
        "727920": 676.0000000000000000
    },
    "variableType": 2,
    "isSet": false,
    "teamNumber": 2,
    "simPageIds": []
}
```

I have a scenario that I have to delete a particular property from the `"values"` property of my document. for example, I want to delete value `"727920"` from the `"values"` property.

Since `"Values"` is not an array, I can't use `$pull` here. What I need is to remove

`"727920" : 676.0000000000000000` from `"values"`.

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [$unset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) as below :

```
db.collectionName.update({},{"$unset":{"values.727920":""}})
```

**EDIT** 
For updating multiple documents use [update options](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) like :

```
db.collectionName.update({},{"$unset":{"values.727920":""}},{"multi":true})
```

Comment: It works @yogesh. Thanks. But I totally have more than 50 documents in my collection like this. But when I execute the above query, the first document only gets updated. What must I do to update all my document in my collection?

Answer (score 5):

You may try the following query using `$unset`

For single document update,

```
db.collectionName.update({ /* filter condition */ }, { $unset : { "ParentKey.ChildKey" : 1} })
```

For multiple documents update,

```
db.collectionName.updateMany({ /* filter condition */ }, { $unset : { "ParentKey.ChildKey" : 1} })
```