# remove a property from an object in an array of objects mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB document like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5589044a7019e802d3e9dbc5"),
  groups:[
    {
      _id: 5a3326d01b2213894672fdd0,
      group_id: '13239517',
      thread_id: 'f32940da-12-15-01-9325790',
      Last_post_id: '981206845'
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried a variation of `$set` and `$unset` using:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({userId}, {groups:{$set: {thread_id: ''}}}, {new: true})
```

when I tried multiple variations of the above code I keep on getting groups where the affected object is only left with an id.

```
[
  { _id: 5a3326d41b2213894672fdd1 },
  {
    _id: 5a332a81479a728ebe4226e5,
    group_id: '13239517',
    thread_id: 'f32940da-12-15-01-9325790',
    Last_post_id: '981206845'
  }
]
```

I've also tried looping over the array of groups removing the key using reduce then just trying to set the groups to this new values like and that didn't work either.

```
let groups = groups.reduce((prev, ele)=>{
  // group_id is passed in as an argument
  if(ele.group_id === group_id){
    let chatThread = ele.thread_id
    delete ele.thread_id
    console.log(ele)
    return chatThread
  } else {
    return prev
  }
}, false)
User.findOneAndUpdate({userId}, {groups}, {new: true})
```

this just doesn't do anything.

My intended result would be where `thread_id` is gone

```
groups:[
  {
    _id: 5a3326d01b2213894672fdd0,
    group_id: '13239517',
    Last_post_id: '981206845'
  }
]
```

Although similar to
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945924/remove-a-field-from-array-element-in-mongodb) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384269/how-to-remove-property-of-nested-object-from-mongodb-document) both of those solutions either don't change anything when saved or remove all properties other than _id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a field from array element in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945924/remove-a-field-from-array-element-in-mongodb)

Comment: As this is a duplicate, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945924/remove-a-field-from-array-element-in-mongodb

Comment: @Veeram I tried those and it did not work for me it would either remove all properties except _id or do nothing at all. I did find a solution though based on those links so thank you very much.
User.findOne({userId}, async(err, user)=>{
            let newGroups = user.groups.map(ele=>{
              if(ele.group_id === group_id){
                return {group_id:ele.group_id,_id: ele._id,Last_post_id: ele.Last_post_id}
              }return ele
            })var updateUserGroups = await User.findOneAndUpdate({userId}, {groups: newGroups}, {new: true})
          })

Answer (score 0):

this did work for me. looks like reduce and map when using delete keyword will not affect the original array I assumed it would since i thought it was passed by reference.

```
User.findOne({userId}, async(err, user)=>{
            let new_groups = user.groups.map(ele=>{
              // group id is passed as an argument
              if(ele.group_id === group_id){
                return {
                  group_id:ele.group_id,
                  _id: ele._id,
                  Last_post_id: ele.Last_post_id
                }
              }
              return ele
            })
            var updateUserGroups = await User.findOneAndUpdate({userId}, {groups: new_groups}, {new: true})
```

Comment: You can use `User.update( {userId}, {$unset: {"groups.$[].thread_id":""}} )` in 3.6 to remove all the thread_ids from group  array.