# updating mongo documents based in map value and remove that value

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

am currently working in Go and have a mongo database (connected via gopkg.in/mgo.v2) so, right now I have a data structure similar to:

```
{
    "_id" : "some_id_bson",
    "field1" : "value1",
    "field2" : {
      {
      "key1" : "v1",
      "key2" : "v2",
      "key3" : "v3",
      "key4" : "v4"
      }
    }
}
```

So, basically what I need to do (as an example) is to update in the database all the records that contains *key1* and remove that from the json, so the result would be something like:

```
{
        "_id" : "some_id_bson",
        "field1" : "value1",
        "field2" : {
          {
          "key2" : "v2",
          "key3" : "v3",
          "key4" : "v4"
          }
        }
    }
```

What can I use to achieve this? I have been searching and cannot find something oriented to maps (field2 is a map). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're asking how to remove a property from a nested object in a particular document, which appears as if to be answered here: [How to remove property of nested object from MongoDB document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384269/how-to-remove-property-of-nested-object-from-mongodb-document).
from the main answer there:

> Use [$unset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) as below :
>
> db.collectionName.update({},{"$unset":{"values.727920":""}}) EDIT For
>   updating multiple documents use update options like :
>
> db.collectionName.update({},{"$unset":{"values.727920":""}},{"multi":true})

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$exists` and `$unset`:

```
query:= bson.M{"$exists":bson.M{"field2.key1":true}}
replace:=bson.M{"$unset":bson.M{"field2.key1":""}}
collection.UpdateAll(query,replace)
```

This should find all documents containing `field2.key1`, and remove that.